# Nodejs Loop and Mongodb Save cause Mongodb MAx connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

imagine the following script

```
var startPage = 1
var endPage = 40



 for (y = startPage; y < endPage ; y++) { 

 var y = Number(y)
 var search = getresult.from.Myapiforexample

search.run().then(function (data) {

   //////////////////

    /// This will generate 35 results//

         var myresult = data.results



   for (i = 0; i < myresult.length; i++) { 
            data.results[i].getDetails().then(function (details) {

              savetodb(details)

            }, function (err) {
                console.error(err);
            });
    }   

}, function (err) {
    console.error(err);
});

}




function savetodb(json) {

    var getsession = function(db, callback) {
          var collection = db.collection('thebase');

              collection.insert(data, function (err, docs) {
              callback(docs);
                 db.close();
              });
      };
       MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
          getsession(db, function(docs) {


              console.log("Recording ok")


          });
      });

}
```

the 1st loop (with y) run 40 Time who each generate 35 results.
So i will have 40 X 35 records to save to Mongo db 
that will reach my mongodb Maxx connection.
so what i'm looking to do is :

create a empty array

```
var myarray = []  // ok 

push each "details" to myarray

myarray.push(details)
```

But my problem is as nodeJS is asynchronous, I will need to wait for the end of the y loop to save to db

so how can i wait for Y loop to finish before send  myarray to the save functions.
Without emplementing a wait time..?

I've tried using callback, promise without any success ..

Comment: y = Number(y) is unneccessary as y is already a number...

Answer (score 0):

You could use Promise.all. At first store the promises in an array:

```
var promises=[];
//in the loop
promises.push(data.results[i].getDetails());
```

So now you can wait for all of them and save them:

```
Promise.all(promises).then(savetodb);//passes all results to savetodb in an array
```

You may want to enable savetodb to take an array as argument, but thats up to you...

---

However instead of opening new connections for every operation, you could simply keep one:

```
var db=new Promise(function(res,rej){//in global scope
 MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
   if(err) return rej(err);
   res(db);
 });
});
```

Now you can access this connection everywhere:

```
db.then(function(db){
  //db is our database
});
```

you can implement error handling like this:

```
db.catch(function(err){
  console.log("fatal db error. shutting down. "+err);
  process.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite complicated stuff. I hope this works, as I'm not able to test it. I basically make heavy use of nested `Promise.all`s, which in your case I believe is necessary:

```js
var startPage = 1;
var endPage = 40;

var searchPromises = [];

// make the searches
for (var y = startPage; y < endPage; y++) {
  searchPromises.push(getresult.from.Myapiforexample.run());
}

// create a database connection
new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(error, database) {
    if (error) {
      return reject(error);
    }
    resolve(database);
  });
}).then(function (db) {
  var collection = db.collection('thebase');
  Promise.all(searchPromises).then(function (dataArray) {
    // dataArray contains an array of an array of search results
    var results = dataArray.map(function (data) {
      // data contains an array of search results
      return data.results.map(function (result) {
        return result.getDetails();
      });
    });
    // results is an array of arrays, flatten it:
    var resultPromises = [].concat.apply([], results);
    return Promise.all(resultPromises);
  }).then(function (results) {
    var insertPromises = results.map(function (result) {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        collection.insert(result, function (error, docs) {
          if (error) {
            reject(error);
          }
          resolve(docs);
        });
      });
    });
    return Promise.all(insertPromises);
  }).then(function (docsArray) {
    // docsArray contains an array of the docs parameter of the callback in collection.insert
    console.log('All recordings OK.');
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Could not insert data into database', error);
  });
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.log('Could not connect to database', error);
});
```

This way, you don't have to create 40 times 35 database conntections.

Answer (score 0):

You get max connection error because of this mere fact:

```
function savetodb(json) {

    var getsession = function(db, callback) {
        var collection = db.collection('thebase');

        collection.insert(data, function (err, docs) {
        callback(docs);
           db.close();
        });
    };
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        getsession(db, function(docs) {

        console.log("Recording ok")


        });
    });
}
```

Each and every time you call this `getsession` function, you open a new connection to mongodb. And you call `getsession` roughly `(endPage - startPage) * (data.results.length)` times, which exceeds the maximum number of connections that your mongodb instance accepts.

What you should do is:

You do `MongoClient.connect` once at the start of your program, store the `db` in a global variable and only after you finish executing `MongoClient.connect` should you start inserting your data and you don't close your `db` as long as your program executes.

That's one way to do things.

But that one way will not scale up for production. For production, you should use connection pools. Which means:

1. At the start of your program, you connect to mongodb a number of times and store each `db` in an array.
2. When you do an insert, you get one `db` from the array
3. After you're done with the insert, you give the `db` back to the array.
4. When there are no available `db`s in the array, you wait for one to become available.

I guess there are a number of connection pool implementations available for mongodb, including quite a few native ones. Just pick one.

Answer (score 0):

I stopped using mongodb as it's overusing diskspace all of a sudden but here it's code working it:

```
     //MONGODB
const collection = client.db("bitfinicon").collection("productpost");
for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    const nanoid = customAlphabet('1234567890', 10)
    // console.log(nanoid)
    people[i] = { ...people[i], "userid": new ObjectId("613dfcca7e7e2014c12dfeef"), "createdat": new Date(), "id": new Double(Number(nanoid())) };
}
```

Nanoid is just a quick way of generating id since mongodb id is slow as itself. Using surrealdb after experiencing those on mongodb